# 100-level discrete maths, induction problem, prove $n^2 \ge 2n + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I've just run into this problem, and was able to go as far, and understand the induction step up to the bolded section. The last part I found in the back of my book, italicized, I can't understand.

Use induction to prove: $n^2\geq 2n + 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\geq 3$.

Base: $3^2\geq 6+1$.

Induction Hypothesis: Assume that $k^2\geq 2k+1$ for $k\geq 3$.

Induction Step: $(k + 1)^2=k^2+2k+1\geq 2k+1 + 2k + 1 = 2(k + 1) + 2k \geq 2(k + 1) + 1$

I went as far as $(k + 1)^2 \geq 2(k+1) + 1$?

Any help, much appreciated

Comment: I realize that the exercise is to use induction and become comfortable with it, but it's worth mentioning that induction can be over-used. Here, if $n>2$, then of course $n^2>2n$. And since we are dealing with integers, that means $n^2\geq 2n+1$.

Comment: @alex.jordan. Yeah I did notice that initially, but like you said, it's about learning to become familiar with induction.. which.. evidently.. haha, but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: So, what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your expansion,

$$\left(k^2\geq 2\,k+1\right)\;\Rightarrow\; \left((k+1)^2 \geq 4\,k+2\right)\tag{1}$$

since, as you have found, $(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2\,k+1 \geq 2\,(2\,k+1)$ by the predicate on the LHS of the $\Rightarrow$ in (1).

But, for $k\geq 1$, we also have $4\,k+2 > 2\, k+3 = 2(k+1)+1$, hence your induction step follows from (1) together with $4\,k+2 > 2 k+3$.

You've clearly got the right idea: you simply seem to be confusing yourself with symbols: this happens to most humans often so (as I have needed to do many times), if this happens to you, I susgest you write the above out in terms of a predicate with a formal definition $P:\mathbb{N}\to\{\text{true},\,\text{false}\}$ (in this case $P(n) = (k^2\geq 2\,k+1)$) and manipulate, with standard first order rules of inference, the truth functions beginning from $P(n_0)=\text{true}$ for the induction basis and $P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$ for the step.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I understand everything you've explained except for the crucial initial step. It's been a long summer so I'm a bit rusty and I feel like I should know this, but what is it about the RHS that causes 2k+1⇒ 4k+2? I'd thought to just insert k+1 for any k.

Comment: @AndréFoote Its the same as in the other answer, and indeed you have worked it out too. We have $(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2 k + 1$. But then we *assume* we have shown that $k^2 \geq 2\,k+1$. So therefore, given this assumption, we must have $k^2 + 2\,k+1\geq 2\,(2\,k+1) = 4\,k+2$. Then we use the formula $4\,k+2>2\,k+3 = 2(k+1) + 1$, hence you have a chain of inferences from your assumption that $k^2>2\,k+1$ leading to $(\mathbf{k+1})^2 >2 (\mathbf{k+1}) + 1$. Hence you have shown that, given $P(k)$, we can infer $P(k+1)$.

Answer (score 6):

You have *assumed* that $\color{blue}{k^2}\geq\color{#af5500}{2k+1}$ for some specific $k$. So $$\begin{align}(k+1)^2&=\color{blue}{k^2}+2k+1\\
&\geq\color{#af5500}{2k+1}+2k+1\\&=2(k+1)+2k\\&\geq2(k+1)+1\end{align}$$ where the last inequality is because $2k>1$.

Comment: +1, especially for the use of color to help the reader spot the predicate: I'd never thought to do this: obvious once it is done. The green doesn't stand out so well, but maybe this is because I am 52.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Agreed about green, but the named colors available are all bad to contrast with blue and also be good on white background. I changed it to a darker orange using html hex.

Comment: @alex.jordan: You get just about the same color with the named color `brown`.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Maybe. I'm red-green colorblind, which is common, and may or may not be relevant here. To me the brown is harder to distinguish from the black if the screen brightness is low.

Comment: @alex.jordan: I just tried them side by side, and I must admit that they're not quite as close as I thought when I was comparing them a few inches apart. The brown is a little redder than your color, which may explain the difficulty.